# Are these idioms, phrases or...?

Tags: phrases

1. "I know north from south" means I know everything or I know a lot of stuff or I have been to Norht and South, so I know a lot (context: people thing about me I do not know anything, but I know north from south.)
2. Ever since I loved you. "Through the springs and the summers" means all the time or since then up to now or I love you no matter what?
   Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is usually "one *doesn't* know north from south" and it means they don't know anything. Since the difference between north and south is such a basic and simple fact, the expression implies that if a person doesn't know even *this*, then they really don't know *anything*. There are countless variations on this expression, all with a similar structure ("doesn't know X from Y" where X and Y are everyday things that should be clearly distinguishable, even to an uneducated person).

Your second expression (which should probably be a separate question) is unintelligible to me. "Ever since I loved you" is not a complete sentence and it's not clear how "through the springs and summers" is supposed to relate to this.

Comment: In terms of the second question: "The long and the short is, ever since that day I loved you. Through the springs and the summers." Is it ineligible now?